# Session not recognized in include() page (NOT A DUPLICATE)

Tags: php, session, include

***IDK why this guy keeps putting it as duplicate it is not I looked at other examples and they won't fix this problem***

I have a session that isn't recognised when I use it on a page that is then included in another page like this:

**nav.php**

```
include('login.php'); // Has session variables in it
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  echo '<span>Dash</span>';
}
else{
  echo '<span>Login</span>';
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

I don't know why, but the code above doesn't work. No matter if they are logged in or not, it will still just show 'Login'.

---

I know for sure that the session is started because the code below works:

**index.php**

```
include('login.php'); // Has session variables in it
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  echo '<span>Dash</span>';
}
else{
  echo '<span>Login</span>';
}
```

---

For some reason when nav.php is included in index.php, it ends up not recognizing the session, but when the code is ran without including any files it works perfectly.

**I have looked at the links to show that this is a duplicate and they aren't helping.**

---

Edit:

Tried running this code:

**login.php**

```
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 30, "/", "domain.com", true); // also tried '.domain.com'
session_name("login_user");
session_start();
```

**index.php**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_COOKIE["login_user"])) {
  echo 'Dash';
}
else { 
  session_unset(); 
  session_destroy(); 
  session_abort(); 
}
```

For some reason, the new code doesn't do anything.

---

I'm not sure if this helps, but I tried echoing the $_SESSION variable and this is what happened:

**nav.php**

```
include('login.php');
echo $_SESSION["login_user"];
```

**index.php**

```
include('nav.php');
```

The output for this was a notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: login_user in nav.php on line 28
```

**But** when I tried echoing the code like this:

**index.php**

```
include('login.php');
echo $_SESSION["login_user"];
```

The output was the actual username.

I think for some reason when you use 'include()' to include the code, that looks for a session, it just fails. When you use the code straight up without including another document that has the code, it works perfectly.

Comment: Try to use Sessioncookie https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: I can see the PHPSESSID & __cfduid cookies in the browser if that helps.. What params should I enforce?

Comment: I‘m currentlly on mobile. Will provide some Ideas tommorow.

Comment: Where do you use session_start()

Comment: It's inside login.php, which is included at the top.

Comment: Try this:
`session_set_cookie_params(60 * 30, "/", "yourdomain", true);
session_name("yourSessionName");
session_start();`
See the Docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).
Then you can check the existens of your Cookie:
`if(isset($_COOKIE["yourSessionName"])) {
   // Cookie is OK
} else {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_abort();
}`

Comment: I can see the cookies it is making, but for some reason, the code doesn't do anything.. Even when I put it in the index, without including it. I'm going to update the main post with the code I used.

Comment: I also added another section because I tried echoing the session.